# Memory segment permissions per user/group - any way to achieve this?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, operating-system, systems-programming

We know there are rwxp/s permissions on memory segments of an elf executable.

Now, I have a user or a group, and I would like them to see .text segment (read access) of a certain executable but nothing else (no access to .bss or .data or .stack). Is there a way to achieve this?

Use case - a not trusted observer to whom I want to prove what the code is doing without disclosing any data the code operates upon.

Comment: Why not just give them read access to the ELF file?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli how do we prove the file is what actually being executed? Although I appreciate an observer would have to have some global view of memory segmentation to be assured text segment shown isn't a dummy either.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Seems to me like an XY problem to be honest. As per proving execution that can be done in different ways e.g. through the output of `top` / `ps` etc.